# GetAdornerLayer() for a control derived from MedialElementBase

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, adorner

I have a WPF control which is derived from MedialElementBase(Base class is UIElement).
This control is used to dislay video from webcam. I need to draw lines on this video. 
I am using WPF Adorners and calling GetAdornerLayer() for above control which always
returns NULL. Am I using this correctly? Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `AdornerLayer` is created by an `AdornerDecorator` or a `ScrollContentPresenter` in the visual tree. By default the `ControlTemplate` for `Window` has one surrounding all its content. If there is neither an `AdornerDecorator` or `ScrollContentPresenter` as a parent to your control, it will return null.